# IPC using msgsnd and msgrcv

Tags: linux, ipc, message-passing

For learning, I wrote 2 IPC programs, a server and a client that use message sending. For some reason, the server does not seem to be receiving the data it has been send. Could you give me some hints on how I could go about debugging such a problem?

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CENTRAL_MAILBOX 1200
#define CLIENT_MAILBOX 1201

struct {
long priority;
int value;
int pid;
} msgp, cmbox;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int uid = 0; // Process id of the server(this process) set to 0
int length = -1; // Length of the structure we are going to send over
int result = -1; // Result of the msgrcv operation
int status = -1;

if ( argc != 2 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./server <temperature>\n");
    exit(-1);
}

printf("[+] Starting server\n");

printf("[+] Creating the mailbox\n");
int server_msgid = msgget(CENTRAL_MAILBOX, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);

printf("[+] Creating a mailbox for the client process\n");
int client_msgid = msgget(CLIENT_MAILBOX, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);

printf("[+] Initializing data to be sent across\n");
msgp.priority = 1;
msgp.value = 31337;
msgp.pid = uid;

length = ( sizeof(msgp) > sizeof(long) ? sizeof(msgp)-sizeof(long) : sizeof(long)-sizeof(msgp) );
printf("[+] Calculating the size of the message we are about to send across=%d\n", length);

// msgrcv(int msqid, void *msgp, size_t msgsz, long msgtyp, int msgflg);
result = msgrcv(server_msgid, &cmbox, length, 1, 0);
printf("Result = %d\n", result);
printf("[+] Received message pid=%d, value=%d, priority=%ld\n", cmbox.pid, cmbox.value, cmbox.priority);

printf("[+] Sending message\n");
// int msgsnd(int msqid, const void *msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg);
result = msgsnd(client_msgid, &msgp, length, 0);

printf("[+] Shutting down server\n");
status = msgctl(server_msgid, IPC_RMID, 0);

if ( status != 0 ) {
fprintf(stderr, "[*] ERROR: closing mailbox failed\n");
}

}
```

My Client :-

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CENTRAL_MAILBOX 1200
#define CLIENT_MAILBOX 1201

struct {
long priority;
int value;
int pid;
} msgp, cmbox;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int temp = atoi(argv[1]);
int uid = getpid(); //7171;
int length, result, status;

if ( argc != 2 ) {
// TODO find actual process id
fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./client <temperature>\n");
exit(-1);
}

printf("[+] Creating server mailbox\n");
int server_msgid = msgget(CENTRAL_MAILBOX, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);

printf("[+] Creating client mailbox\n");
int client_msgid = msgget(CLIENT_MAILBOX, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);

printf("[+] Initializing the data to be sent across\n");
cmbox.priority = 2;
cmbox.value = 1337;
cmbox.pid = uid;

length = ( sizeof(msgp) > sizeof(long) ? sizeof(msgp)-sizeof(long) : sizeof(long)-sizeof(msgp) );
printf("[+] Calculating the size of the message we are about to send across=%d\n", length);

printf("[+] Sending message to server\n");
result = msgsnd(server_msgid, &cmbox, length, 0);
printf("Result = %d\n", result);

result = msgrcv(client_msgid, &msgp, length, 1, 0);
printf("[+] Received message pid=%d, value=%d, priority=%ld\n", msgp.pid, msgp.value, msgp.priority);

printf("[+] Removing the mailbox\n");
status = msgctl(client_msgid, IPC_RMID, 0);

if ( status != 0 ) {
printf("Error when closing mailbox\n");
}

}
```

Comment: Check the return values of your msg*() function calls. Also, is there some reason you are using Sys V message queues rather than POSIX message queues?

Comment: No particular reason no. I'll try POSIX next. the return value of msgsnd is 0

Comment: What about the return value of msgrcv? I asked about POSIX message queues because you are more likely to find helpful resources about those than the older kind.

Comment: msgrcv does not return. The call is blocked as it does not seem to be receiving any input

Answer (score 1):

Your server blocks on the 1st `msgrcv()` because it expects message of type 1 (what you called priority, in your `msgp, cmbox` structures):

```
// msgrcv(int msqid, void *msgp, size_t msgsz, long msgtyp, int msgflg);
result = msgrcv(server_msgid, &cmbox, length, 1, 0);
```

When the client send a message of type 2:

```
printf("[+] Initializing the data to be sent across\n");
cmbox.priority = 2;

// [...]

printf("[+] Sending message to server\n");
result = msgsnd(server_msgid, &cmbox, length, 0);
```

Have a look at how to use the `msgtyp` value in the man page:

> ```
> int msgsnd(int msqid, const void *msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg);
> ssize_t msgrcv(int msqid, void *msgp, size_t msgsz, long msgtyp, int msgflg);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The `msgp` argument is a pointer to caller-defined structure of the following general form:
>
> ```
> struct msgbuf {
>     long mtype;       /* message type, must be > 0 */
>     char mtext[1];    /* message data */
> };
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> `msgrcv()`
>
> [...]
>
> The argument `msgtyp` specifies the type of message requested as follows:
>
> - If `msgtyp` is 0, then the first message in the queue is read.
> - If `msgtyp` is greater than 0, then the first message in the queue of type `msgtyp` is read, unless `MSG_EXCEPT` was specified in `msgflg`, in which case the first message in the queue of type not equal to `msgtyp` will be read.
> - If `msgtyp` is less than 0, then the first message in the queue with the lowest type less than or equal to the absolute value of `msgtyp` will be read.